# Increase processing speed FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I try to scale video from a gallery using FFmpeg library on android. 
I am using the following command:

val command = arrayOf("-i", background, "-vf", "scale=$width:$height", out)

But for it`s very slow. For the video 10 sec, I need to wait around one minute.
My video resolution 2160x3840
As I understand now FFmpeg uses CPU for processing. Do have some way to use GPU or make it process faster?

Comment: Are you rendering to x264? For x264 you can try `-preset ultrafast`. For VP8 `-quality good -cpu-used 3`. Also try `-hwaccel cuvid` or `-hwaccel dxva2` and `-gpu any`.

Comment: Yes x264
this is full command:
            val command = arrayOf("-i", background, "-i", video, "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-filter_complex", "[0]scale=$newWidth:$newHeight[vas];[1]crop=iw:ih/2:0:0[rgb];[1]crop=iw:ih/2:0:ih/2[alp];[rgb]scale=$w:$h[rgbs];[alp]scale=$w:$h[alps];[rgbs][alps]alphamerge[va];[vas][va]overlay=x=$x:y=$y", out)

Comment: Find out how many cpu cores and threads the processor has. Try `-threads 4` or -`threads 8`.